# Вывод ошибки

Tags: php

Вообщем у меня  есть три ссылки в зависимости от которой я нажал выводятся определенные файлы. Все хорошо все выводиться только помогите сделать чтобы выводилась ошибка. То есть если установилось exucutable и не нашлось ни одного файла на сервере то вывести "Программы не найдены" если photo то "Фотографии не найдены" и так же с документами.
PHP:

```
$types = array( "executable" => array( "exe", "msi" ),"photo" => array( "jpg", "png","gif" ),"document" => array( "doc", "docx", "pdf" ),);

    $type = $types[ $_POST[ "file_type" ] ];

    if( $type )
    {
    show_files_type( $type );
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ошибка";
    }
    function show_files_type ($type) {
    $connect = ftp_connect('********');
    $connect_login = ftp_login($connect, '****', '******');
    ftp_chdir($connect, '**********/');
        $list_files = ftp_nlist($connect, ".");
        if (count($list_files) !== 1) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($list_files); $i++) {
        if ($list_files[$i] !== "upload") {
        $extension = substr(strrchr($list_files[$i], '.'), 1);
        foreach ($type as $type_val) {
        if ($extension == $type_val) {
        $time_modify = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", ftp_mdtm($connect, $list_files[$i]));
        $size_file = substr(((ftp_size($connect, $list_files[$i]) / 1024) / 1024),0,5)." Мб";
        $link_download_file = '<a href="*************/'.$list_files[$i].'"><button class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span> Скачать файл</button></a>';
        $remove_file = '<a onclick="delete_file(this.id)" id="'.$list_files[$i].'"><button class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Удалить файл</button></a>';
            echo '<tr><td>'.$list_files[$i].'</td><td>'.$time_modify.'</td><td>'.$size_file.'</td><td>'.$link_download_file.'</td><td>'.$remove_file.'</td></tr>';
        }
        }
        }
    }
    }
    ftp_close($connect);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> То есть если установилось exucutable и не нашлось ни одного файла на сервере

Что значит "установилось"?

Если я все правильно понял, то, возможно, вам поможет, такое решение:

```
    foreach ($type as $type_set) {
        
        $flsExsts = false;
        
        foreach ($list_files as $file) {
            
            if($file !== 'upload') {
                
                $extension = substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1);
                
                if($extension == $type_set) {
                    
                    $time_modify        = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", ftp_mdtm($connect, $file));
                    
                    $size_file          = substr(((ftp_size($connect, $file) / 1024) / 1024), 0, 5)." Мб";
                    
                    $link_download_file = '<a href="*************/'.$file.'"><button class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span> Скачать файл</button></a>';
                    
                    $remove_file        = '<a onclick="delete_file(this.id)" id="'.$file.'"><button class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Удалить файл</button></a>';
                    
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$file.'</td>
                        <td>'.$time_modify.'</td>
                        <td>'.$size_file.'</td>
                        <td>'.$link_download_file.'</td>
                        <td>'.$remove_file.'</td>
                    </tr>';
                    
                    $flsExsts = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(!$flsExsts) {
            echo 'Files of type '.$type_set.' does not exists';
        }
    }
```

Суть в том, что мы не пересчитываем сначала файлы, а потом внутри каждого цикла проверяем подходит ли файл по расширению, а наоборот, сначала проходимся по списку типов файлов и внутри цикла считаем их количество. Если количество после цикла пересчета равно нулю - выводим соответствующее уведомление.

А вообще, проверять соответствие файла определенному типу по расширению - не очень хорошая идея. Можно поменять расширение у файла и скрипт опознает его иначе. Если интересно и есть время, то проверку соответствия лучше сделать через Mime types. Для работы с ними в PHP есть замечательное расширение - [finfo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.fileinfo.php). Про более конкретные реализации можно почитать [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.finfo-file.php).

Comment: Не заработало почему то..